# `$set` can replace the field value of Boolean type in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is a sample schema for the question:

```
const sample = new Schema({
  scope: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['draft', 'published'],
    default: 'draft',
  },
  isOutOfService: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});
```

And a sample data of the schema:

```
const data = {
  _id: 1,
  scope: 'draft',
  isOutOfService: false,
};
```

Now I want to update the field `scope` value to `published` and `isOutOfService` value to `true`.

I use the code below with mongoose:

```
const updated = await sample.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: 1
}, {
  $set: {
    scope: 'published',
    isOutOfService: true
  }
}, {
  new: true,
}).lean().exec();
```

And the result of the update operation is:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  scope: 'published',
  isOutOfService: false,
}
```

I don't know why the `scope` was replaced and the `isOutOfService` was not?

Comment: Does it works if you do this with a simple update query instead of findOneAndUpdate ?

Comment: Try without $set :)

Comment: Or maybe you should also try with {returnNewDocument: true} instead of {new: true} ?